# Samba module full_audit is logging actions that didn't occured

Tags: monitoring, samba, auditd

Our company has a file server, a Debian Squeeze 64 bits, sharing some folders to Linux servers using NFSv2 and to Windows workstations using Samba.

I want to log access to a specific set of shared files.

I installed and configured the **full_audit** Samba module, which log Samba operations, using the following configuration.

```
[MY_SHARE]
    path = /share/directory_to_watch

    vfs objects = full_audit
    full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S
    full_audit:success = pread read
    full_audit:failure = none
    full_audit:facility = local7
    full_audit:priority = warning
```

The problem is that logs appears logging actions that the user didn't do : from a Windows workstation, you go in a folder by clicking on it and stop here, 
and then every files in the folder are marked as read in the logs. So full_audit is clearly not a reliable tool. Or am I doing something wrong ?

I tried to install the Linux tool **auditd** on my file server. This tool logs system calls on the machine where it is installed. 
But when users access the files I want to monitor via the NFS mounts on others servers, system calls
occurs on the server mounting the share, not on the file server (that is the way NFS works). And I want to avoid a situation where I am supposed to deploy monitoring tool everywhere.

So questions are : does anyone met the same problem than me with the **full_audit** Samba module ? Does anyone know a good way to log file access on a NFS server ?

Comment: Have you considered that for a directory listing your file browser will probably request the file-size, owner and permissions , timestamps etc. of all the files in that directory? That means a  [**`stat`**](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) on each file in that directory... Exactly what full_audit should record...

Comment: So now I know why all these lines appears in the logs. Thanks. Do you have any ideas for the other part, an efficient way to log file access on  NFS/Samba shared folders ?

Comment: I'm not shure, but i think you can disable windows explorer to acces all files on network folders.